# How do I write a matches expression in Pig with a wildcard in the middle?

Tags: sql, apache-pig

If for example I have a SQL LIKE expression '%blah%zoop%', how would I write it in Pig? Do I just use .* in place of %?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 0):

See [matches](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Comparison+Operators) which is equivalent of 'like' in sql.

```
B = FILTER A BY (fieldname matches '.*blah.*zoop.*');
```